# Checking if email already exists in Jquery.validate

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It is probably something simple that I am missing but I am trying to validate an email and make sure it does not already exist in the database. I have used a few different examples found here on Stack Overflow and am still not getting results. I went ahead and added a row in the username table in the database and am purposely trying to get an error message. The rest of the jquery.validate script is working fine (Missing email, invalid email) Yes I have read the documentation and tried the example in the documentation, but still getting no error message when typing the email address I know is in the database. Here is what I have. Thanks!

The HTML

```
<form id="form-register" role="form" action="." method="post">
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <lable>Email</lable>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
</form>
```

The code used by jquery.validate via my own javascript file so I can use custom text on the validation

```
$().ready(function(){
   $("#form-register").validate({
      rules: {
         email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
               url: "checkemail.php",
               type: "post"
            }
         }
      },
      messages: {
         email: {
            required: "Please enter an email address",
            email: "This is not a valid email address",
            remote: "That email is already Registered"
         }
      }
   });
});
```

And the PHP code which does not seem to fire when debugging the PHP. So I cannot tell if the values are being received by the PHP file or not.

```
require("classes/Db.class.php");
require ('core/core_functions.php');
$db = new Db();

   if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
      $email = $_POST['email'];

      $rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :email", array("email"=>$email));

      $total_rows = count($rows);
         if( $total_rows > 0 ){
            echo 'false';
         }else{
            echo 'true';
         }
     }
```

I guess I do not understand how the AJAX passes the value of email to the PHP file without any data tags. I have tried to add the data to the rules declaration in the jQuery, but that still did not work. Even tried get in desperation. Thanks for any help anyone can give me to help me understand.

Comment: It would be so much easier to just write an ajax function for this.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), it must return the **JSON string `"true"`**, not just `true` on its own. You need quotes around it, by my understanding.

Comment: Well it also helps if the file were in the right folder on my site and not in another project all together. I at least can get my PHP debugger to work now but it gets caught up on the query to the database for some reason. It is sending the email to the php file though. But i'm not getting to the "true" statement before it crashes in the PHP file. I'm not sure I understand what you mean Niet... Is it not returning 'true'? So are you saying it should be '"true"'?

Comment: Okay I got it working... Turns out the PHP file was not even in my project folder but in another project. Also had a problem with the query statement that for some reason did not like a dash in the table name (I will remember that one) Do I need to delete this question as it was my goof with file structure, or do I keep it here as unanswered?